# How do I draw graphics in C# without a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I currently have a Console application. How would I draw graphics to the screen without having to have a form.

Comment: Why you don't just create a form and run it in a secondary thread?

Comment: Because what I am doing requires no forms.

Comment: A form is just an abstraction for a window. You can just skip the fact that it is a form and use it as a common window. You can also use windows api CreateWindowEx skipping the usage of Windows.Form dll, but it will require you to do quite a lot of work since you don't have any GDI function in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT - based on CuddleBunny's comment, I have created a class that will basically "draw graphics on the screen."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    class test : Form
    {
        public test() : base()
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.BackColor = Color.Purple;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Purple;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 200, 200);
            this.Invalidate(); //cause repaint
        }
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new test());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

**old faulty answer**

---

You can get the hwnd of another window and draw on that. I'm not sure how to draw on the entire screen though, I've always wondered that myself.

A simple example :

```
            Process p = Process.GetProcessById(0); //id of the process or some other method that can get the desired process
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(p.MainWindowHandle))
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a window of some kind to draw graphics to. You can't just draw directly to the screen.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but this application called puush (which lets you upload screenshots) http://puush.me/ draws a rectangle  on-screen for you to select the region of the screen to capture, and it appears to not need any window. Not advertising, but I've always wondered how it does that.

Comment: I'm sure it uses a "window" but the window it is drawing to does not have any chrome. You can recreate this effect by creating a Forms Application, setting the window's style to "none" and the background to transparent. After that the only things the user will see is the objects you add to the form.

In the case of puush.me, I am sure it creates a fullscreen window with a transparent background.

Comment: CuddleBunny, that's worthy of a standalone answer (especially if you juice it up with some bare-bones code).

Comment: There are some special API functions that allow you to draw some simple shape also over other windows, most of them are however now deprecated. The usual way to do this is to create a semitransparent window.

Comment: Most applications that could paint directly on the screen without using a form were actually getting a reference to the root Window Handle, which represents the screens drawing surface, then making PInvoke calls against that HWnd.  Most of these application no longer work as of windows Vista, since it was deemed a security threat.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw on the entire screen without a window using directx if you create a full screen directdrawsurface.  The screen is all yours (no windows desktop at all).